# Error in OAuth mediator version WSO2 EI 7.0.2

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server

I am trying  to  use OAuth mediator for validating an API .   I am using WSO2IS as my IAM server .  OAUth mediator is configured to connect WSO2IS server . using URL 'https://localhost:9443/services'     while invoking i get followign exceptions .  Please see Exception stack below
[

> 2020-05-27 13:47:27,939]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.commons.util.MiscellaneousUtil} - Error loading properties from a file at from the System defined location: nhttp.properties
>   [2020-05-27 13:48:01,105]

**INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} - Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService]**

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:276)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at

Answer (score 1):

I have updated keystore and it was working